# How to pack http request body using libcurl?

Tags: c++, http, gzip, libcurl

Is it possible to send requests using libcurl in gzipped form? How can I do that?

Comment: Your question isn't clear although I'll try; You mean you want the request, and not the reply, to be encoded in gzip? Well, someone correct me if I'm wrong but in HTTP you usually get the reply encoded and not the request header/packet.

Comment: Well, I see, it really is not standard. So what we did - we just extended the standard just for our application, by adding Content-Encoding: gzip header to requests and packing data into gzip manually.